# Change the fingerprint of a video file with ffmpeg without re encoding it

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-encoding

I am searching for a way to edit a video file to not have the same fingerprint anymore.
It should not have a high CPU impact and all the tracks of the original file should be copied (so it needs `map 0`)
Do you have better ideas or a working prompt for me?

So far I experimented with removing the last frame and adding an empty subtitle track, but the ChatGPT generated commands did not work or have unwanted side effects.

For subtitle this was the best I could get: `ffmpeg -i "$file" -f srt -i "$subtitle_file" -map 0 -map 1 -c copy -scodec mov_text -metadata:s:s:0 language=eng -metadata:s:s:0 handler_name="Empty Subtitle" "$output_file"` where i first created an "empty" subtitle file and then it should add this, but the output file did not have the subtitle.

And for removing the frame I got this: `ffmpeg -i "$file" -vf "select='not(mod(n,1))',setpts='N/(24*TB)'" -c:v copy -an -sn -y "${file%.*}_frame_removed.${file##*.}"` but here it gave me an error aboutFiltering and streamcopy cannot be used together.

Comment: What is a fingerprint in this context?

Comment: @MarcusMüller something like a hash, that changes, whenever the file is edited. But not only on file level, but rater looks at the (video-) content itself.

Comment: We need an actual definition of what that is, otherwise it's impossible to say.

Comment: The problem is, that I don't know it 100% myself, what is sufficient. But I think my two examples should be sufficient to change the fingerprint.

Comment: maybe you can try `ffmpeg -i xxx.mp4 -c copy -metadata title="new title" out.mp4` to change something with the metadata, which will change the file's checksum

Comment: @BrianHolsen thank you this would be my fallback variant, but I would feel safer to edit the video or audio stream itself.